# Unable to send file through ASP.NET controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Unable to send text file through ASP.NET controller. My file exists under `wwwroot->Files->text.txt`. It throws error

> FileNotFoundException

However when I check the file path, the file exists.

```
public IActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

    var filePath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "wwwroot", "Files", "test.txt");

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        return File(filePath, "text/plain", "test.txt"); // Sends a plain text file as the response.
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound(); // File not found, return a 404 response.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Below is working fine. Not sure why above code didn't work

var fileName = "test.txt"; // Change this to your file's name
var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath+"\Files\", fileName);

```
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        return PhysicalFile(filePath, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound(); // File not found, return a 404 response.
    }
```